# TrySelect on IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I would like to write an extension for IEnumerable similar to Select called TrySelect, TrySelect will ignore selection of any element where the select Func throws an exception.

I have the following, which works.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> TrySelect<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        List<TResult> ret = new List<TResult>();
        foreach (TSource input in source)
        {
            try
            {
                ret.Add(selector(input));
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

I would like to know how to write the extension without using a list so as to preserve the IEnumerable behaviour of not populating the elements until they are called.

Comment: Catching exceptions regardless of type is risky. Consider making this generic on a specific exception type, or refactoring the underlying function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use yield return:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> TrySelect<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        foreach (TSource input in source)
        {
            TResult result;
            bool wasSuccesful = false;
            try
            {
                result = selector(input);
                wasSuccesful = true;

            }
            catch { }
            if (wasSuccesful)
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

MSDN docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: I would like to return all the entries which do not throw and exception, will this do that?

Comment: yes it will. that's what `wasSuccessful` tracks.. it won't `yield return` the value if the `selector` threw an exception. This code should be equivalent to your sample code, except for being evaluated lazily.

Comment: @jimmyjambles can you mark it as answered if this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @John answer's on 2022 :

Code won't compile because `result` is potentially unassigned.

Use default operator like :

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> TrySelect<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                                   Func<TSource, TResult> selector,
                                                                   Action<Exception, TSource> handleError = null)
    {
        foreach (TSource input in source)
        {
            TResult result = default(TResult);

            bool wasSuccesful = false;
            try
            {
                result = selector(input);
                wasSuccesful = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                handleError(e, input);
            }

            if (wasSuccesful)
                yield return result;
        }
    }
```

I have also added optionnal "error handler"